# SSH Session freezes when running 'high bandwidth' commands (like htop)

Tags: ssh, openbsd, vps

My client, OpenBSD is connected to a VPN, and the server, OpenBSD is also connected to a VPN with the SSH port being forwarded.

I can complete any number of tasks just fine, but if, for example, I `tar -xzvf lots-of-files.tar.gz` it will display a few and then freeze, requiring me to close my xterm and reconnect and `tmux a` back into my session. If I try to launch very 'heavy' tui apps like htop all I get is a black screen with a stuck cursor.

Of note, I can still SEND commands while in this state. I can change tmux panes, or I can ctrl+c htop and then reconnect and reattach and all is well.

This VPS is low spec, with only 512mb, but currently it is not doing *anything*. And doesnt pull more than 10% CPU utilization or more than 100mb of ram utilization.

Answer (score 2):

My wireguard interface and my vio0 interface had mismatched MTU values. I set them all to the same value of 1420 with `doas ifconfig $interface mtu 1420 up` and that fixed it. Able to run htop and vim and tmux and screen and all that jazz as much as I want now without issue.

Comment: You might have an issue like a firewall dropping ICMP packets that triggers [PMTUD blackhole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery#Problems). Not requiring PMTUD by lowering MTU is an alternate way to solve this.